# PHP Regex help - search for string in middle of regex

Tags: php, regex

I need a little bit of help with my regex.

Haystack is the sourcecode of a whole page. I'm searching for links which have jpg and jpeg at the end and "pdp-zoom" somewhere in the middle.

A link like this:

https://mosaic04.ztat.net/vgs/media/packshot/pdp-zoom/BR/71/1A/01/7Q/11/BR711A017-Q11@4.jpg

Or this:

```
//mosaic04.ztat.net/vgs/media/packshot/pdp-zoom/BR/71/1A/01/7Q/11/BR711A017-Q11@4.jpg
```

I have that:

```
(http)?s?:?(\/\/[^,|"\']*\.(?:jpg|jpeg))
```

and need to integrate that "pdp-zoom".

I'm using that with php 5.6 and preg_match_all.

Comment: Where is your question? As a hint, if you already know how to match the string `jpg`, it shouldn't be too hard to extend that knowledge to match `pdp-zoom` as well.

Comment: Personally, I'd split this up. First use DOM or some other XML parser to pull out the relevant tags, _then_ check the name. wouldn't even require regex.

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
(https?:)?//[^'"\s]*/pdp-zoom/[^'"\s]*\.jpe?g
```

**Explanation:**

```
(https?:)?          # http: or https:, optional
//                  # double slashes
[^'"\s]*            # 0 r more any character that is not quotes or spaces
/pdp-zoom/          # literally /pdp-zoom/
[^'"\s]*            # 0 r more any character that is not quotes or spaces
\.                  # a dot
jpe?g               # jpeg or jpg
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/e36FeC/4)

Comment: Your regex gives incorrect solution for this string `https://mosaic04.ztat.net/abcpdp-zoom/abc.jpg/BR711A017-Q11@4.jpg` Check this [demo](https://regex101.com/r/e36FeC/3)

Answer (score 0):

Try Regex: `(?:http(?:s)?:)?\/\/[^,|"\']+?\/pdp-zoom\/[^,|"\']+?\.(?:jpg|jpeg)`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pMUROJ/1)

Comment: This seems to be matching across lines, see https://regex101.com/r/pMUROJ/2

Answer (score 0):

You may use this regex,

```
(https?)?:?\/\/.*?pdp-zoom.*?\.jpe?g(?=\s|$)
```

Which will completely match a URL only if it has `pdp-zoom` inside it and ends with either `jpg` or `jpeg`.

Here this `(?=\s|$)` look ahead ensures the URL matches in full and not partially in a larger string like this,

https://mosaic04.ztat.net/abcpdp-zoom/abc.jpg/BR711A017-Q11@4.jpg

If we don't put look ahead, in the regex, then the regex will match partially and give this URL on above string,

```
https://mosaic04.ztat.net/abcpdp-zoom/abc.jpg
```

Which is incorrect and hence the need of look ahead.

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/e8K5b0/1)**

Comment: Both of your lines that you present should not match actually do.

Comment: When I go to your demo link - all 3 lines are matched?  Including "https://mosaic04.ztat.net/abcpdp-zoom/abc.jpg/BR711A017-Q11@4.jpg" or delete the preceding "/" in the second line just before pdp-zoom and it still matches.  Did you include a demo link before you modified it?

Comment: @Mark: Yes, all three links in my demo should indeed match as per OP's post. Why do you think it should not match? Can you link a demo showing what should not match and is matching?

Comment: Well, look at the other answers and the OP's examples.  They all "assume" /pdp-zoom/ is its own directory.  Perhaps that is inaccurate but it would appear that it is.  I could be wrong but then the OP's examples are very misleading.

Comment: @Mark: In his post OP has mentioned `pdp-zoom` and not `/pdp-zoom/` although the example he has taken contains `/pdp-zoom/` (which is a subset and his example could have been like `/aaapdp-zoomaaa/`) so why do you think I should give preference to example data rather than his literal words? And if I use regex like this `/pdp-zoom/` then this example `/aaapdp-zoomaaa/` will not match which will not go along with what OP said, that it should contain `pdp-zoom`. And technically other answers are not correct in accord with just from my above example.